# Simple Django form and get value submitted

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like to create a `Django form` very easy, than I would like to pick up the value from both fields.

This is my **form** :

```
class SettingsForm(forms.Form):
    download_validity = forms.CharField(label='Expiry Download')
    flag_validity = forms.CharField(label='Expiry Flag')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, I have a **view** :

```
class SettingsView(FormView):
    template_name = 'settings.html'
    form_class = SettingsForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        subtitle = _("Manage Settings")
        context_data = super(SettingsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_data['subtitle'] = subtitle
        return context_data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        download_validity = form.cleaned_data['download_validity']
        flag_validity = form.cleaned_data['flag_validity']
        print(download_validity)
        print(flag_validity)
        return super(SettingsView, self).form_valid(form)
```

And finally my **template view** :

```
{% block main %}

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <form autocomplete="off" method="get" action="">
        <fieldset>
          <legend class="title"><span class="name">{% trans 'Expiry Download link' %}</span></legend>
        </fieldset>
        {{ form.download_validity|as_crispy_field }}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="UpdateDownload" value="{% trans 'Update' %}"/>
      </form>
    </div>

  <div class="row">
      <form autocomplete="off" method="get" action="">
        <fieldset>
          <legend class="title"><span class="name">{% trans 'Expiry New Publication' %}</span></legend>
        </fieldset>
        {{ form.flag_validity|as_crispy_field }}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="UpdateFlag" value="{% trans 'Update' %}"/>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>

{% endblock main %}
```

I don't know why, but I would like to get value thanks to cleaned_data but the print function doesn't display anything. I don't know if I missed something but all seems to be right.

I have to create 2 forms in my forms.py file instead of one ?

Answer (score 0):

In your template you should create the form outside of your rows, like so:

```
<form ...>
    <div class="row">
    <input .../>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input .../>
    </div>
</form>
```

Have you made sure if your form is both valid and also being posted? (You could just simply debug inside your view and a few more prints that check if the request is POST etc. Maybe you are also missing your CSRF-Token as it isn't defined in your template (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/)

You could also let the form render itself. For example via `{% crispy form %}` in your case (https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html)